# What is the best way to teach a friend to sing? (Improving hearing ability)

Tags: harmony, voice, teaching

In the past, I thought that singing (I mean hearing the notes and being able to produce the same note) was given at birth and couldn't be improved. But in a year, a friend of mine improved himself so much that I realized I was wrong. This friend I am talking about wasn't able to harmonize at all and would go off tune all the time. Couldn't even stay in the same note. But now he can very much sing and hear/produce correct notes etc.

So another friend of mine asked me to teach him. Now I am asking what is the best way to do this? Right now I am playing a note from the piano and trying to make him produce the same note one by one. If there are good tecniques I would like to hear them! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should refer the second friend to the first? :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak That's a good idea :) However he got professional help :)

Answer (score 1):

One method could be a simplification of one I use to write large vocal parts - as even after all these years & can't just write them all down, or even sing them all one after another straight out of my head.*

First, pick a simple song, a 3- or 4-chord wonder to start with. Maybe a country-style song - something with a strong melody but nothing too 'clever' in the way of melodic structure.

Play simple chords left hand & the melody right hand - which will give the melody something to sit on, rather than being free-floating with no reference.

Emphasise which note of the chord references which melody note, then point out any that aren't part of a simple triad - pick tunes where these are more passing notes, rather than something that will to a beginner appear to just sit entirely in the cracks. Stay away from complex or chromatic structures initially. This should start to train your friend to be able to get the first note right just from the chord - a necessary skill, ongoing.

That should give them sufficient grounding eventually that you can progress to something more complex.

*I extend this method when writing so that I'm playing the existing parts, leaving me to sing the new one until I'm happy with it. I then swap which to sing & which to play until I've got them all, before I even record the first part.